# 2 grub bootloaders

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub, boot-loader, manjaro

I have a windows 10 pc and decided to install Manjaro after partitioning my hardrive.

***Note*** *although they both work I could only access windows 10 using uefi and the linux grub in legacy support.*

Now here is my problem. I deleted the manjaro partition and decided to install arch linux and although I still have to go to either uefi or legacy to access either OS, 
When I go into legacy support and boot normally I get the grub rescue prompt... to access arch I have to configure my boot order to get into arch which is surprising because at the prompt I see a partition of arch(which is normal) **but** I can also see the Manjaro partition which i deleted.

Basically if I boot normally the grub loader tries to access manjaro and am forced to use the method stated above to get to arch even though arch also has its own boot loader it isn't prioritized.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Boot up Arch and

```
update-grub
```

with root privileges.